# Send Mutliple Select Array to Controller and Add Several Records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many-through, multiple-select

I have a `template`, a `user` and `user_templates`. `user` has many `templates` through `user_templates`.

Currently, whenever a new template is created a user_template record is created as well. This works perfectly with creating 1 record.

`Template Create Controller`:

```
def create
  @template = Template.new(template_params.merge(user: current_user))
  if @template.save
    save_user_templates(current_user.id, @template.id)
    redirect_to dashboard_url
  else
    render(:new)
  end
end
```

`Save User Template function`

```
def save_user_templates(user, template)
  UserTemplate.create(user_id: user, template_id: template)
end
```

Now I want to implement a 'Multiple Select' so I can select multiple users, click save, which would then create a record for each user in the user_template table at once.

My idea is to pass an array from the view to the controller and then loop through that array and save each record before redirecting. **Question is: How do I do that?**

Answer (score 1):

Figured out a solution after trying various things. Unfortunately, I did not see the reply in time. Here is what I did.

`View`

```
.form-group.has-feedback
  .text-muted
    = f.label 'Which users should see this?'
  = f.collection_select :user_templates, User.all, :id, :name, { include_hidden: false }, multiple: 'true'
```

`Controller`

```
def create
  @template = Template.new(template_params.merge(user: current_user))
  if @template.save
    save_user_templates(params[:template][:user_templates], @template.id)
    redirect_to dashboard_url
  else
    render(:new)
  end
end

def save_user_templates(users, template)
  users.each do |user|
    puts user
    UserTemplate.create!(user_id: user, template_id: template)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over the array of users and perform the same action on each of them.

`def save_user_templates(user_id_array, template)
  user_id_array.each { |user_id| UserTemplate.create(user_id: user_id, template_id: template) }
end`